# When calling expire or pexpire in redis, is time rounded up?

Tags: redis, lua

I am calling `expire` for an existing redis key. Let's say I am passing 5 for the value. If the key already exists and is 4.75 seconds away from expiring, does it stay at 4.75 seconds or is it rounded back up to 5 seconds?

I can use `pexpire` to get more granularity, but there is still a rounding problem with partial milliseconds - unless milliseconds is the smallest granularity in redis...

If it helps, here is my rate limit script, which takes a key, an amount to increment and a millisecond rate limit window, which keeps decrementing until the key drops out, at which point the next call adds the key and sets a fresh expire time. The new incremented value is then returned.

```
local f,k,a,b,c c=ARGV[2] f=redis.call k=KEYS[1] a=f('incrby',k,ARGV[1]) b=f('pttl',k) f('pexpire',k,math.min(b<0 and c or b,c)) return a
```

*UPDATE*
New rate limit script that does not have partial time issue, it only sets expire if the key does not have an expire set at all:

```
local f,k,a,b f=redis.call k=KEYS[1] a=f('incrby',k,ARGV[1]) b=f('pttl',k) if b<0 then f('pexpire',k,ARGV[2]) end return a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it stay at 4.75 seconds or is it rounded back up to 5 seconds?

It is back to full 5 seconds TTL.

> unless milliseconds is the smallest granularity in redis...

It is milliseconds, for version 2.6 or greater

See [Expire accuracy](https://redis.io/commands/expire#expire-accuracy)

> In Redis 2.4 the expire might not be pin-point accurate, and it could
>   be between zero to one seconds out. Since Redis 2.6 the expire error
>   is from 0 to 1 milliseconds.

And

> Keys expiring information is stored as absolute Unix timestamps (in milliseconds in case of Redis version 2.6 or greater).

You can play with some Lua scripts if you want to verify

```
EVAL "local result = {'Time at start', 0, 'Expires in (ms)', 0, 'Time at end', 0} \n result[2] = redis.call('TIME') \n redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) \n result[4] = redis.call('PTTL', KEYS[1]) \n result[6] = redis.call('TIME') \n return result" 1 myKey 5
```

Friendly view of the script:

```
local result = {'Time at start', 0, 'Expires in (ms)', 0, 'Time at end', 0}
result[2] = redis.call('TIME') 
redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) 
result[4] = redis.call('PTTL', KEYS[1]) 
result[6] = redis.call('TIME')
return result
```

Comment: So in theory you could have an expire script that runs at least every millisecond that sets a pexpire to some constant ms value and it could prevent the expire time from decrementing?

Comment: Yes, in theory you can call `EXPIRE myKey timeInSecs` every millisecond, and the UNIX timestamp storing the expire-at time will keep sliding 1 ms at a time.

Comment: Ok, I am using redis to rate limit in a server cluster, I guess I will need to either hope a ms passes between calls or decrement or something...

Comment: Unless internally redis only stores the ms value, then there would be no partial milliseconds and setting the same millisecond value over and over would have no loss of elapsed time?

Comment: Looking at source here, looks like microseconds is used internally, which is unfortunate for my use case: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/3243252cb05869ed4abd49f06e45d7eac4912298/src/expire.c

Comment: Updated question with a solution that does not have an issue with this